# serializing an NSXMLDocument object

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSXmlDocument object which is constructed from an XML file. How can i serialize

the said document. I have seen NSPropertyListSerialization class, but could not use as it is

not plist file.

Answer (score 2):

Call `-XMLData` on it; you'll receive an instance of `NSData` which can subsequently be written to disk.

Also; you could use [`-XMLDataWithOptions`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002406-BCICDAHD), for much the same result.